# How to convert below curl command in to php formate?

Tags: curl, dreamfactory

I want to convert this terminal command into php curl format, or http post can you please help?

```
curl -i -k -3 -X PATCH "http://localhost:8080/api/v2/db/_table/todo/1" \
  -H "X-DreamFactory-Api-Key: <api key for app in the apps tab>" \
  -H "X-DreamFactory-Session-Token: <session token from login response>" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{ "complete" : true }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use cURL. See http://codular.com/curl-with-php for some examples.

Comment: I had been able to solve my problem, but your provided example is very helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/api/v2/db/_table/todo/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"complete\" : true }");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Dreamfactory-Api-Key: <api key for app in the apps tab>";
$headers[] = "X-Dreamfactory-Session-Token: <session token from login response>";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply